# Why can't I update my system via shell script?

Tags: server, 14.04, apt, updates, scripts

I have a very simple script, let's call it `update.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Updating system..."
sudo apt-get udpate
sudo apt-get udgrade
```

Running this script, throws the following error:

```
me@host $ ./update.sh
Updating system...
E: Invalid operation udpate
E: Invalid operation udgrade
```

This is Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS x64.

```
me@host $ uname -a
Linux host 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running the command from shell directly works as desired:

```
me@host $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://some.mirror.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://some.mirror.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://some.mirror.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://some.mirror.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://some.mirror.ubuntu.com trusty Release
[...]
```

Why is that? Any idea?

Comment: You have some typos.. its update and upgrade.

Comment: @vertoe command-line **clearly** showing error: `E: Invalid operation udpate` so check spelling right is `update` not `udpate` and same for `upgrade`!

Comment: in my case it was a matter of saving with the right line endings. I was running vagrant in windows and saving a script file with windows settings so it wouldn't read correctly in the linux box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`udpate` and `udgrade` are wrong!

try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Updating system..."
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```